# Fibonacci sequence generator not working for 1 or 2 as inputs but it works for the rest of the sequence?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Can someone explain to me why my fibonacciGenerator function doesn't work with this code? I understand why it works with the second code tho but I just don't get why the first one doesn't.

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {

  if (n > 0) {
    var fArray = [];
    fArray.push(0);

    if (n >= 2) {
      fArray.push(1);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      fArray.push(fArray[i] + fArray[i + 1]);
    }
    console.log(fArray);
  }
}

fibonacciGenerator(1);
fibonacciGenerator(2);
```

Second code working :

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {

  if (n > 0) {
    var fArray = [];
    fArray.push(0);

    if (n >= 2) {
      fArray.push(1);
    }
    for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
      fArray.push(fArray[i - 1] + fArray[i - 2]);
    }
    console.log(fArray);
  }
}

fibonacciGenerator(1);
fibonacciGenerator(2);
```

Comment: Why don't you push `0 and 1` in every case? There should be no conditional for that.

Comment: The first example will run your `for` loop whenever `n > 0`, even if `n >= 2` is not met. When `n = 1` then your loop will fail, because it looks up the *next* two values, but because `n >= 2` evaluates to `false`, you will only have 1 key in your `fArray`. When `n = 2`, then the loop starts at `0` and will add the first and second keys together (`0 + 1`), but you've already added those numbers. The second example *only* starts looping whenever `n >= 2`, guaranteeing that there are two keys in the `fArray` (`0` &  `1`) and uses the *previous* two keys to calculate the following number.

Answer (score 1):

The first code is printing 2 extra Fibonacci number this is because:

you are first pushing 0 and 1 into the array as:

```
var fArray = [];
    fArray.push(0);
  
    if (n >=2 ){
        fArray.push(1);
    }
```

and then you loop over again till n times. Because of this reason it prints two extra Fibonacci numbers.

the solution is to either loop over n-2 time or to use the second code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fArray = [];
fArray.push(0);

if (n >= 2) {
  fArray.push(1);
}
```

The initial condition is to cover `n=1: [0]` and `n=2: [0,1]`

The 2nd code is working because the loop only starts when `n` is greater than `i`, so means it skips the loop with `n < 2`.

For your problem, you don't skip the loop when `n < 2`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  fArray.push(fArray[i] + fArray[i + 1]);
}
```

You can imagine the result will be like below when `n < 2` with your loop.
Note that the inital value is `fArray = [0]`

```
fArray.push(fArray[0] + fArray[1]); //fArray[1] is undefined because you only have 1 item in your array
```

In this case `fArray[0] + fArray[1] ==> 0 + undefined = NaN`

So that's why your logic does not work when `n < 2`

To correct it, you need to avoid the loop if `n < 2`

```
//if n=1 or n=2, it won't trigger the loop due to `i < n-2`
for (var i = 0; i < n-2; i++) {
   fArray.push(fArray[i] + fArray[i + 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea to have `i` start with 0 instead of 2, and to adjust the body of the loop accordingly, is fine, but there is one thing that the first version didn't adjust: the stop condition of the loop.

By setting `i=0`, the first version loops 2 times more than the second version. You should also alter the end condition in the same way: instead of `i < n`, it should have `i < n - 2`, so to ensure the number of iterations is the same as in the second version.

Not related to your question, but the `console.log` should better be placed outside of the function. The job of the function should be to *return* the array, not to print it. So also, when `n > 0` is false, it should return an empty array.

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {

  var fArray = [];
  if (n > 0) {
    fArray.push(0);

    if (n >= 2) {
      fArray.push(1);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) {
      fArray.push(fArray[i] + fArray[i + 1]);
    }
  }
  return fArray;
}

console.log(fibonacciGenerator(1));
console.log(fibonacciGenerator(2));
```

Answer (score -1):

First you have to identify the pattern.

```
Fibonacci series -> 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21

Term             -> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  8


0th term =0, 1st term =1
```

From the second term,

```
2nd = 1st term + 0th term = 1+0 = 1
3rd = 2nd term + 1st term = 1+1 = 2
4th = 3rd term + 2nd term = 2+1 = 3
5th = 4th term + 3rd term = 3+2 = 5
nth = (n-1) + (n-2)
```

since the first 2 terms are fixed, you have to start for loop from i= 2.
Also, according to the above shown pattern, you have to use following code inside the for loop.

```
fArray.push(fArray[i - 1] + fArray[i-2]);
```